# Get a thread by name/label in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I would like to know if there is a way in Objective-C to get a thread by its name or label?

```
dispatch_queue_t newQueue = dispatch_queue_create(@"NameOfTheQueue", NULL);
```

This creates the queue. So, in another module, is there a way to get that queue?

Something like:

```
dispath_queue_t theQueue = dispatch_find_queue_by_name(@"Name...");
```

Comment: Queues are not threads. Queues can run on different threads.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as the names need not be unique.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing built into the Dispatch functions that let you find a queue other than the main queue.

You could write your own little wrapper that stores queues and their names in a dictionary for lookup. But keep in mind that a queue's name doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: ... and if you're storing the queue in a dictionary, you could just store the reference in a more meaningful (direct) way right away. :)